How can I create a BasePage in MAUI with sections?
In my .NET8 MAUI application, I have a lot of pages with the same XAML code and code behind. For example, I have the advertisement at the bottom of the XAML pages and use the same code to remove the space from the command line.
I found a lot of examples with the BasePage with C# code but none related to the XAML. What I like to do is to have only 1 BasePage where I manage the advertisement and then in the other pages add the content. For example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ads="clr-namespace:Plugin.MauiMTAdmob.Controls;assembly=Plugin.MauiMTAdmob"
             x:Class="LanguageInUse.Views.BasePage"
             Title="BasePage">

    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="First"></VerticalStackLayout>
        <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="Second"></VerticalStackLayout>
    
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Grid.Row="2"
            Margin="0,5,0,0"
            BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ads:MTAdView
                x:Name="ads"
                AdSize="AnchoredAdaptive"
                AdsId="{Binding AdsId}"
                IsVisible="true" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

So, in a page that inherits from BasePage, I like to add the XAML in the section First or Second. I'm not sure I can do that. Is there any example? Is it possible to do that?

You could use a ContentPresenter I guess https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-8.0#substitute-content-into-a-contentpresenter

Step 1 - Create BasePage using ControlTemplate and ContentPresenter:
<ContentPage
  x:Class="MauiSamples.Views.BasePage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

  <ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>

      <Grid RowDefinitions="250,*,250">

        <Label
          Grid.Row="0"
          FontSize="Title"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"
          Text="Header"
          VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />

        <Label
          Grid.Row="2"
          FontSize="Title"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"
          Text="Footer"
          VerticalOptions="Center" />

      </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>
  </ContentPage.ControlTemplate>

</ContentPage>

Step 2 - Use BasePage:
Create a new page that inherits from BasePage and add content like you would for any other page or view:
<views:BasePage
  x:Class="MauiSamples.Views.PageWithBase"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiSamples.Views">

  <Grid>
    <Label
      FontSize="Title"
      HorizontalOptions="Center"
      Text="Hello from Page"
      VerticalOptions="Center" />
  </Grid>

</views:BasePage>

Note that the root must not be ContentPage but instead should be your BasePage.
It's important that any page that uses your BasePage inherits also from BasePage in the code-behind:
public partial class PageWithBase : BasePage
{
    public PageWithBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

Also note that you can only use a single <ContentPresenter /> instance per view or page that you want to use as a base. In all other cases, you need to define properties of type <ContentView />.
You can see a working example in my MAUI samples repo.

Thank you for your answer. Do you have an example of how to use the ContentView? How can I bind values in the ControlTemplate?

You need to use TemplateBindings for that
